# Change the position of MBProgressHUD Loader

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I Want to Change Position of loader center to top

Comment: use `yOffset` for MBProgressHud object

Comment: MBProgressHUD *Hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
hud.yOffset = 250.0; //For bottom location.

Answer (score 2):

But if u want it on top than set it to,

```
hud.yOffset = -100.0;
```

Comment: thnks...buddy you save my time

Answer (score 0):

use for bottom location

```
MBProgressHUD *Hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
hud.yOffset = 250.0; //For bottom location.
```

And for upper location

```
MBProgressHUD *Hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
hud.yOffset = -250.0; //For upper location.
```